# CMake could not find the VTKConfig.cmake

Tags: cmake, vtk

I'm trying to compile a program in CMake but I'm getting this error.

```
By not providing "FindVTK.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "VTK", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "VTK" (requested
version 6.1) with any of the following names:

VTKConfig.cmake
vtk-config.cmake
```

I can't find the relevant files (VTKConfig.cmake or vtk-config.cmake) on the machine but do have VTKConfig.cmake.in (which also doesn't work).
Does anyone know where I can download the file from, or what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you just have the VTK source code but haven't built it yet. VTKConfig.cmake.in is a template used by CMake to generate the VTKConfig.cmake file in the build and install directory. Look at http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building to see how to build VTK.

Comment: I've built VTK but there is no `VTKConfig.cmake` to be found anywhere. There is a `vtk-config.cmake` though but I'm not sure if its the same thing. Has `VTKConfig.cmake` been deprecated?

Comment: @Olumide they are the same. `In this mode, CMake searches for a file called <lowercasePackageName>-config.cmake or <PackageName>Config.cmake`

Answer (score 5):

When you have successfully built VTK you can give CMake a hint where to look for VTK with the `VTK_DIR`-parameter:

```
cmake -DVTK_DIR=/path/to/vtk/build-directory /path/to/your/source-directory
```

Comment: Mind explaining what you mean by `source-directory`?

Comment: The source directory of your CMake-based project, i.e. where your root-CMakeLists.txt file lives.

Answer (score 2):

If you have successfully built VTK, you would end up with a `VTK-Release-build` folder containing all the build files, one of which is `VTKConfig.cmake`. Your program is not able to find this file. You just need to set an environment variable named `VTK_DIR` before running your program. You can do so by running:

`export VTK_DIR=/path/to/VTK-Release-build/`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem recently, and solved the issue in my case.

In `CMake/vtkWheelPreparation.cmake` in VTK, if the wheel build is enabled, `VTK_INSTALL_SDK` defaults to `OFF`, which usually defaults to `ON`. If you are setting `VTK_WHEEL_BUILD`, then this happens:

```
if(NOT DEFINED VTK_INSTALL_SDK)
  set(VTK_INSTALL_SDK OFF)
endif()
```

See

- https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/5957f789760eab5a1c456db802237089a43aac33/CMake/vtkWheelPreparation.cmake#L75-L77
- https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/commit/a514cbb8021132e178ce26e3a65788593f70cd95

***Explicitly setting `VTK_INSTALL_SDK`  to `ON` in your config should fix this issue and provide `vtk-config.cmake` in the build directory.***

I included this fix in my CMake configs for building VTK here (these configs closely follow what VTK publishes to PyPI): https://github.com/banesullivan/vtk-cmake

```
set(VTK_INSTALL_SDK ON CACHE STRING "")
set(VTK_WHEEL_BUILD ON CACHE STRING "")
```

Comment: This answer saved my day, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"`FindVTK.cmake`"the file of cmake is made in build directry.

please add this Path. `export VTK_DIR=/path/VTK-Release-version/build`

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer