# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindVTK.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "VTK", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "VTK" with any of
  the following names:

    VTKConfig.cmake
    vtk-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "VTK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "VTK_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "VTK" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(Sphere)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(Sphere MACOSX_BUNDLE Sphere.cxx)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(Sphere ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  target_link_libraries(Sphere vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif()
```

Comment: what have you tried, and what is your question

Comment: i have this error when trying to create example using cmake"Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid "   CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):By not providing "FindVTK.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "VTK" but CMake did not find one.

Comment: You need to do what the error message tells you.

Comment: @SalmaFerchichi: Without additional information your question is no more than any of other questions with the same error message: https://www.google.ru/search?q=By+not+providing+"FindVTK.cmake"+site:stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake could not find the VTKConfig.cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467230/cmake-could-not-find-the-vtkconfig-cmake)

Comment: Have you installed vtk ? Or built it yourself ?